# AS3 Timer out of sync on reload

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a sequence of animations that run while an audio clip is being played. I trigger these sequences by using a **TimerEvent.TIMER** event every 1000 milliseconds. Then using the **Date class** I convert the **SoundChannel.position** into *seconds and minutes* and I detect the appropriate time from the *seconds and minutes* to play the sequence in order to flow with specific times in the audio clip.

The method I thought would be effective....However, sometimes and very rarely when I "reload" the swf I get these weird overlapping of the sequences sometimes not playing in order or playing out of time( this is of course after everything is already preloaded).

What could be causing this? What would be a better solutions besides doing frame by frame animation?

My code looks like this..

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent){
                        var d:Date = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0,channel.position);
                        switch(true)
                        {
                            case d.getMinutes() == 0 && d.getSeconds() == 8 :
                                addText(phrases.shift(),237,122); break;
                            case d.getMinutes() == 0 && d.getSeconds() == 15 :
                                addText(phrases.shift(),20,126,22);  
                                break;
                            case d.getMinutes() == 0 && d.getSeconds() == 16 :
                                removeChild(texts.shift().parent);
                                slides.slideShow(); 
                                var tween:Tween = new Tween(texts[0],"y",Strong.easeOut,texts[0].y, 63,3,true);
                                tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH,function(){
                                                        addText(phrases.shift(),181,100,22); 
                                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                                                   addText(phrases.shift(),181,129,42,true);
                                                                   }, 150);
                                                       });

                                break;
                            case d.getMinutes() == 0 && d.getSeconds() == 22 :
                                removeChild(texts.shift().parent); break;
                            case d.getMinutes() == 0 && d.getSeconds() == 23 :

                                slides.slideShow();
                                break;
                            case d.getMinutes() == 0 && d.getSeconds() == 24 :
                                removeChild(texts.shift().parent);
                                break;
                            case d.getMinutes() == 0 && d.getSeconds() == 25 :
```

Comment: http://ppgpl.com/xmas2013/ here is a demo so you can see what's try using reload or replay and you would see that the word transitions are sometimes off (don't clear the cache)

Comment: Does the device performance have anything to do wit throwing off the timing?

Comment: I currently have the swf set to 24fps...should I increase this? Would increasing it increase performance or help eliminate any sort of latency on it?